# Coveralls shows 0% coverage for node.js project

Tags: node.js, mocha.js, travis-ci, istanbul, coveralls

I can not seem to get Coveralls to display coverage for my node.js project. Here's my setup:

- node.js project on [github](https://github.com/forrert/mongoose-model-security)
- tests with mocha
- coverage with istanbul
- travis-ci for CI
- using node-coveralls to send coverage data to coveralls

I created the following .travis.yml file:

```
language: node_js
node_js:
  - 0.11
  - 0.10
after_success:
  npm run coveralls
```

And have the following script in my package.json file:

```
"coveralls": "istanbul cover ./node_modules/mocha/bin/_mocha --report lcovonly -- -R spec && cat ./coverage/lcov.info | ./node_modules/coveralls/bin/coveralls.js"
```

Coveralls recognizes all affected files (index.js and my lib folder) but it does not display any coverage for any of the files.

Here's what a build looks like on coveralls: https://coveralls.io/builds/1851378

This is istanbul's output if I run it locally (just to demonstrate, that there is in fact some test coverage, also the generated lcov.info file looks just fine):

```
=============================== Coverage summary ===============================
Statements   : 87.85% ( 253/288 )
Branches     : 75.34% ( 55/73 )
Functions    : 86.25% ( 69/80 )
Lines        : 87.85% ( 253/288 )
================================================================================
```

Any suggestions on what I might be missing to properly display coverage in coveralls?

BTW I also tried to upload coverage results to coveralls locally using the repository token and node-coveralls. The result is the same...

Comment: A couple days later and it does now display the correct coverage. I believe there is an issue with coveralls, when a project is added that already has existing sources and tests. I needed to "touch" all files (i.e. update them) to trigger the coverage values to update.

Answer (score 0):

I've had this happen to me, I had to delete the Coveralls repo and re-add it.